# how to get multiple form data in a unique way?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one form which has two text fields. One is Price and another one is share.These text fields are repeating for every row. I am extracting the values after submit in a post array. But the `POST` array coming in a normal way. I want it in a specific way like below.

```
<td colspan="3"><label><?php echo form_error('amount'); ?></label><input type="text" class="textsmall" name="post_cost[]" id="<?php echo $cust_id_cur; ?>" value="<?php echo set_value('amount'); ?>" /></td>

<td colspan="3"><label><?php echo form_error('share'); ?></label><input type="text" class="textsmall" name="post_share[]" id="<?php echo $cust_id_cur; ?>" value="100" /></td>
```

These are the two text fields. When i submit the POST array is like this........

```
post_cost                             
(                                      
[0] => 324123
[1] => 324123
[2] => 324123
[3] => 324123
[4] => 324123
[5] => 324123
)

post_share
(
[0] => 100
[1] => 100
[2] => 100
[3] => 100
[4] => 100
[5] => 100
)
```

But i want two of the above arrays like this. There is filed called `$cust_id_cur` that is unique filed. I want values of each array against those id's. What i mean is there six rows totally so there will be six `cust_id's`.

```
post_cost
(
[$cust_id_cur] => 324123
[$cust_id_cur] => 324123
[$cust_id_cur] => 324123
[$cust_id_cur] => 324123
[$cust_id_cur] => 324123
[$cust_id_cur] => 324123
)
```

why i am asking like this is my order of `cust_id's` are not always same. So i will give against `cust_id`. When i submit i need to save them in the database against that `cust_id`. So i want array like the above.

Comment: The simplest way i can think of is `array_map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the index with your variable in the loop:

```
<td colspan="3"><label><?php echo form_error('amount'); ?></label><input type="text" class="textsmall" name="post_cost[<?php echo $cust_id_cur; ?>]" id="<?php echo $cust_id_cur; ?>" value="<?php echo set_value('amount'); ?>" /></td>
                                                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^ here

<td colspan="3"><label><?php echo form_error('share'); ?></label><input type="text" class="textsmall" name="post_share[<?php echo $cust_id_cur; ?>]" id="<?php echo $cust_id_cur; ?>" value="100" /></td>
                                                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^ here
```